# Laravel - Linux(ubuntu) Real-time process and show output on webpage(blade)

Tags: linux, laravel, shell, symfony, ubuntu

I want to get the real-time output of a running process on my server. For the script I made something simple in bash:

Script 1 (script.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

y=0;

while [ $y > 0 ]; do
y=$((y+1))
sleep 1;
echo $y
echo "I am baking pies. I have $y so far."
done
```

Script 2 (test.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

~/script.sh > /dev/null &
pid=$!

echo $pid
strace -e trace=write -s1000 -fp $pid 2>&1 \
| grep --line-buffered -o '".\+[^"]"' \
| grep --line-buffered -o '[^"]\+[^"]' \
| while read -r line; do
printf "%b " $line;
done
```

The second script's role is to run the first one, get it's pid and than trace the output of that pid. On the server side this should be enough but I may be wrong. However, on the laravel side I couldn't figure a way to get the live output of that script.

Laravel, using Symfony (using the Symfony Docs example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

```
$process = new Process(['/test.sh']);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

The script works almost like it should be, but there is a problem:

When the script runs laravel only prints the pid and doesn't wait for the output of the strace command. Now, is there a way to get the live output of the script while it is running? If it is not possible using Laravel and Symfony alone could I achieve it by using VueJS (which I am familiarized with and practiced in the past few months)?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-input-and-output-stream-for-processes)?

Comment: Indeed I tried. It still shows only the PID and doesn't wait for the rest of the output. Just made a test. When trying the "$process->run()" instead of the "->start" I get a timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can do like that

for example i created one script **`test.sh`** and store in **laravel root project** ..

```
a=0

while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
   echo $a
   sleep 1
   a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

> if you are ubuntu user then give a permission to execute a script file permision
>   like that

```
sudo chmod +x test.sh
```

now in laravel create **`new console command`**

> php artisan make:command test

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class test extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'test';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'test description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $process = new Process([base_path('test.sh')]);
        $process->start();

        foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
            if ($process::OUT === $type) {
                info($data);    //output store in log file..
                $this->info($data);  //show output in console..
                //       $this->info(print_r($data,true)) // if output is array or object then used
            } else {
                $this->warn("error :- ".$data);
            }
        }

        $this->info("get output");
    }
}
```

for more information read this [article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-input-and-output-stream-for-processes)

Comment: Could you further explain how I could get the output to be displayed on the webpage?

Comment: @GMBeniamin ok used socket.io see this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d